# SQL - Find matching string and stop if not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure and this involves matching a list of strings in a table with a column in an another table. If even one string of text in the column is wrong when compared to the table then the procedure will break.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQxNF.png)

Comment: please post the image as text,some sample data,expected result..Look here on how to improve question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Jay, should CUSTID match TEMPID? I suppose it should, but there is a debate under an answer about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple rule:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableToMatch T2
          WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ListTable T1 WHERE T1.Template=T2.Template))
    THROW;
```

If you would like to be more precise, return message:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableToMatch T2
          WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ListTable T1 WHERE T1.Template=T2.Template))
    THROW 50000, 'Procedure is too crazy to finish', 0
```

If you would like symetric match, you can use FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
IF EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM TableToMatch T1
        FULL JOIN ListTable T2 ON T1.Template=T2.Template
        WHERE T1.Template IS NULL OR T2.Template IS NULL)
    THROW 50000, 'Procedure is too crazy to finish', 0
```

Comment: What if there is an element in ListTable which does not exist in TableToMatch?

Comment: Now symmetrical match is handled, but a problem still remains: what if the templates are matching, but CUSTID does not match TEMPID?

Comment: If I want to update a column in the TableToMatch with the CUSTID on the ListTable, do I do an update after THROW? Thanks

Comment: ALTER TABLE TableToMatch ADD item_id int

-- Look at Type in TableToMatch table and see if it exists against ListTable
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableToMatch  T2
          WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ListTable  T1 WHERE T1.Template=T2.Template))
    THROW 50000, 'Type cannot be matched with Cr_Description_Template_Type table', 0

-- Insert the CST_ID into TableToMatch table based on CST_ID of ListTable
 UPDATE TableToMatch 
 SET item_id = T1.CUSTID 
 FROM ListTable  T1
 JOIN TableToMatch T2 ON T1.Template = T2.Template

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `not exists`:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from tomatch m
            where not exists (select 1 from list l where l.template = m.template)
           )
   )
    return 'Bad'  -- or whatever you want to return
else return 'Good';
```

If you have in index on `list(template)`, then I think this is the fastest way to approach the problem.

Comment: What if there is an element in list which does not have a match in tomatch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check both directions to make sure that you handle all differences:

```
if exists(
select 1
from List
where not exists (select 1
                  from Temp
                  where List.CUSTID = Temp.TEMPID and List.Template = Temp.template)
union
select 1
from Temp
where not exists (select 1
                  from List
                  where List.CUSTID = Temp.TEMPID and List.Template = Temp.template))
return 0;
else return 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tryi running this query:

```
DECLARE @CountOfNonMatchRecords INT
SELECT 
@CountOfNonMatchRecords = COUNT(T.Template)
FROM <TableToMatch> T
LEFT JOIN 
<ListTable> L ON L.Template = T.Template
WHERE L.Template IS NULL

IF @CountOfNonMatchRecords > 0 THEN
BEGIN
--Break your procedure
END
```

Comment: You do not compare CUSTID with TEMPID. What if there are templates with the same name but with differing CUSTID and TEMPID? Also, what if there is an element in T which does not exist in L?

Comment: @Lajos: What the question asked simplies into fact that if any string in table T is not available in table L then do a break. The question never mentioned any other condition. The posted image shows the result I expect from my query. The given query gives expected result and I think I can fairly expect Jay to add his own clauses and join wherever required.

Comment: The question asks for matches, which is a symmetric relation. Your code does not handle that. Also, if you take a look at the picture, you will see that CUSTID and TEMPID are matching as well. Your answer failed to address them.

Comment: @Lajos: The pic doesn't highlight CUSTID and TEMPID matching. The question speaks about not finding the string and the image highlights the string that is in table T and not in table L. :)

Comment: It is because there is the difference in that example. If an element in T is missing (due to removal, for example), but all T elements have matches in L, then your code will not handle even the task you wanted to handle, since a missing element will not be observed. Also, I stand to my point that matching is symmetrical. CUSTID and TEMPID should be handled as well. If you assume that they are not necessarily matches, then you need to at least mention that in your answer.

Comment: @Lajos: One thing I can say my answer misses on is Swiimngs and Swimming sound similar and if I consider that it should consider spelling of Swiimngs to be wrong then I understand it won't work.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, hence my down-vote. I explained the reasons. Let me know if you corrected the answer to review it and possibly remove the down-vote.

Comment: @Lajos: May be the query doesn't handle the missing element as you say but it was never in the spec in the first place. Also the spec never speaks about matching CUSTID and TEMPID and it doesn't look to me as if both represent same thing. As I understand all he wanted to know if there is something in table T that doesn't match with content in table L. For me table L works as master table and table T as transaction table and entries in transaction table is validated against the master table as it looks from the picture.